# This branch is not ahead of the upstream master

Tags: git, github

I have an old branch, at that time the head was named: main.
Later we changed the head as master. Now I want to create a PR of that old branch but its not allowing me to create the PR as the buttons are disabled
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first to rebase locally your old branch (assuming you are the only one working on it) on top of the new `origin/master`

```
cd /pth/to/repo
git fetch
git switch your branch
git rebase origin/master
git push --force
```

Then check if you can make a PR.